# structural vhdl: creating a "main function"

Tags: vhdl

I would like to create a structural VHDL file that implements a "main" function. The "top-level" file would be design and the program that runs the code would be prog. Assuming that fulladd_pack contains the fulladd component, how do I "link" the two VHDL files?

*I also don't get the arguments in main in order for this to work.

```
-- design.vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.fulladd_pack.all;

ENTITY design IS
    port(Cin        :   IN STD_LOGIC;
            X,Y     :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
            S       :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
            Cout, Over  :   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END design;

ARCHITECTURE struct OF design IS
SIGNAL C,temp   :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO 15);
BEGIN
            main: prog PORT MAP(Cin,X,Y,S,C,Cin);
END struct;
```

---

```
 -- prog.vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.fulladd_pack.all;

ENTITY prog IS
    port(Cin        :   IN STD_LOGIC;
            X,Y     :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
            S       :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
            Cout, Over  :   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END prog;

ARCHITECTURE struct OF prog IS
SIGNAL C,temp   :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO 15);
BEGIN
            instance0: fulladd PORT MAP(Cin,X,Y,S,C,Cin);
            output: fulladd PORT MAP(Cin,X,Y,S,C,Cin);


END struct;
```

Comment: Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), missing the package declaration, there are semantic errors assigning input signals to outputs (where are Over signals used?). design doesn't look like if uses fulladd_pack unless there's a component declaration in there for prog (otherwise missing). There are drive conflicts on S, Cout, and Over on  the two full_add instantiations, simply connected in parallel.  c isn't declared as it is used, temp isn't used. Linking is elaboration, after everything analyzes (compiles). What VHDL tool?

Comment: I think by "link" you mean to instantiate the entity `prog` in the architecture of `design`. You are on the right way. But, what are the signals `C` and `temp` for? Why did you not just pass the input/output signals of `design` to the instance `main`? And to get help on `prog`, you have to either post the component declaration of `fulladd` from the package or just assign some (random) values to the output, so that `prog` can be compiled.

Comment: Ill edit my question and explain what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the point. VHDL, as a "programming language", models concurrency, dataflow, and the passage of time. A model is composed of large numbers of elements ('processes') with data ('signals') flowing between them. A built-in kernel in your simulator handles the concurrency and time flow.

At the "top level", you write a testbench, which instantiates the model, and you apply stimulus (by driving signals which are inputs to the model). The stimulus forces data around the model. This carries on until you stop providing stimulus, at which point everthing else (should) stop.

So, no main. Write a testbench. 'Linking' is an internal concept in the simulator; forget it. Just simulate your source files together.